# How to schedule notifications in Kotlin for android with a time array?

Tags: kotlin, notifications, alarmmanager, scheduling, android-workmanager

Hi I want to schedule notifications with a notification array:

```
val timesArray = arrayOf("5:45", "17:58", "13:57", "13:58")
```

Whats the best way? Using WorkManager or AlarmManger?

I already have a function to simplify sending notifications that works..

```
 val notificationHandler = NotificationHandler(context)
    val notificationTitle = "It's almost bedtime"
    val notificationText = "x  min until it's time to sleep"
    notificationHandler.sendNotification(notificationTitle, notificationText)
```

This is the function:

```
fun sendNotifications(notificationTitle:String, notificationText:String) {
    val notificationBuilder =
        NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default_channel_id")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setContentText(notificationText)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setAutoCancel(true)

    val notification = notificationBuilder.build()
    val notificationId = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)
}
```

This is the desired function, atm the timeArray is still hardcoded:

```
   fun scheduleNotification(notificationsCount:Int, context: Context) {
    val timesArray = arrayOf("5:45", "17:58", "13:49", "13:59")
    
    for (time in timesArray) {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
        val parts = time.split(":")
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, parts[0].toInt())
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, parts[1].toInt())
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        
        //Logic to send schedule the notifications
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use a **WorkManager** because it is more reliable. If someone reboots the device, it will still work. It also takes less battery.

Comment: If you want to schedule notifications on the exact times, then you have to go with **AlarmManager**. WorkManager cannot be used to specify exact times like 5:45, depending on the device current situation such as battery saving mode, or other factors, the notification may arrive late. Work manager work best for tasks that are periodic, or executed only once, without specifying specific time.

So, your only way to accomplish your goal is to use **AlarmManager** and set an exact time, I haven't used  AlarmManager yet, so maybe someone else help you with the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did acomplish once with workamanger but it did't work when the app was closed because it did a loop and once didn't plan all the scheduled times at once.

Answer (score 0):

I have the **solution** for my problem, this code works. So **notifications will be send on the given times**, when the time is already past, it wil set it for the next day. The **time array is still hardcoded**, but you can easily **add such array as argument to the function**. Hope it helps. Did't find this solution on the internet yet.

```
fun scheduleNotifications(notificationsCount:Int, context: Context) {
    val timesArray = arrayOf("5:45", "11:30", "16:43", "16:44")
    for(time in timesArray){
        scheduleNotification(time,"Almost time to sleep! "+time, "a message", context)
    }

}
fun scheduleNotification(notificationTime: String, notificationTitle: String, notificationMessage: String, context: Context) {
    val hour = notificationTime.split(":")[0].toInt()
    val minutes = notificationTime.split(":")[1].toInt()
    val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent = Intent(context, NotificationReceiver::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("title", notificationTitle)
        putExtra("message", notificationMessage)
    }
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, hour+minutes, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes)
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)

    //If the time is already passed set it for the next day
    if (Calendar.getInstance().after(calendar)) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
    }
    // Schedule the notification
    alarmManager.setExact(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        calendar.timeInMillis,
        pendingIntent
    )
}
```